# onDetach called when fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im having a trouble displaying the same fragment after orientation change. Im putting it to backstack and popping back. It jumps to onCreateView and so on, but then it is calling onDetach, which causes to display wrong fragment.. the code is like:

```
    //fragment
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

    @Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    this.getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
}
```

and in main

```
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>1){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

im i missing something?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you change the orientation, your Activity gets recreated and hence the fragment hosted within your Activity gets recreated and so your fragments entire lifecycle methods are getting called again.

If you want to handle the configuration changes using fragments, please check the below link: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: I know, but it stays in backstack still, so i can somehow easily pull it or not? The lifecycle is alright, it goes through onAttach, onCreateView, but why its trying to detach itself immediately ? Its not called when the fragment is created for the first time...

Comment: anyway its a way to simply handle that, so i mark it as a correct answer, but there must be other way too, right? And im not speaking about onRetainNonConfigurationInstance nor retaining activity..