# What is the correct way to call a method on ViewPager fragments when fragments become visible to user in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a `TabLayout` that uses a `ViewPager` to show different fragments in tabs. I want to call a method (`beginGettingData()` to be precise) on the fragments when they become visible to user. There are two solutions that I used (and searched about for two days) and the result is I still get exceptions regarding fragment not being attached to the activity.

The first method I used is with fragment's `setUserVisibleHint(true)`. I did something like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if (shouldGetData) {
            beginGettingData();
        }
    }
}
```

This approach gave me the `activity not attached exception` and it is true. since this method is being called before fragment's `onCreateView` method.

So I thought of a second approach and I used `ViewPager`'s `addOnPageChangeListener` and called `beginGettingData` method in `onPageSelected` method of the listener like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    TabFragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(position);
    fragment.beginGettingData();
}
```

This works for me if the activity is started from another activity in my application. For example if my `MainActivity` uses `startActivity` to start my `TabLayout` activity. But the problem occurs when the activity is restarted in anyway. For example when the user presses home button, not come back to the application for a long time (which makes android system to kill the activity), and then return to the activity by opening the application again. Or a more simple example would be when the screen rotates. In these scenarios, the `onPageSelected` method is called before `onCreateView` (unlike when the activity is tarted fresh) and then again I get the `activity not attached exception`.

I know I can check that if the fragment is added to the activity or not, but problem is that for the first time, there will be no data to show the user and thus it is not an option for me to use. I MUST call `beginGettingData()` somehow when the fragment is shown to the user.

So what do you suggest me to do?

ps: this is my complete code of the activity that hosts the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_files);

        mViewPagerOnChangePagelistener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (!mDataList.get(position)) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                    TabFragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                    fragment.beginGettingData();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        };

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.files_list_view_pager);
        setupViewpager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.files_list_tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mViewPagerOnChangePagelistener);

        mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPagerOnChangePagelistener.onPageSelected(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupViewpager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        MediaFragment videoMediaFragment = new MediaFragment();
        MediaFragment pictureMediaFragment = new MediaFragment();
        Bundle videoMediaBundle = new Bundle();
        Bundle pictureMediaBundle = new Bundle();
        videoMediaBundle.putInt("media_type", MediaHelper.MEIDA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        pictureMediaBundle.putInt("media_type", MediaHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO);
        videoMediaFragment.setArguments(videoMediaBundle);
        pictureMediaFragment.setArguments(pictureMediaBundle);
        mAdapter.addFragment(videoMediaFragment, "video");
        mAdapter.addFragment(pictureMediaFragment, "picture");
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<TabFragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public TabFragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(TabFragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you onDetached() method?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646130/ondetach-called-when-fragment

Comment: I don't have anything in my `onDestroy` method since my activity is configured to be portrait only. I tested orientation change to see if the problem still occurs. My main problem Is with when the user exits and comes back to the app again

Comment: I am not able to get a clear cut of your question.let's make things simple. you have a tablayout with 3 tabs in your activity. and you have your data in one of the fragments. now if you move to next activity and come back to previous activity what is happening?

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me on this. Here's the problem : I have a `MainActivity` which calls `TabLayoutActivity` using `startActivity` method. When the TabLaoutActivity` is started this way, everything is ok and `beginGettingData` will be called on every fragment that become visible. Now suppose you are in `TabLayoutActivity`. You press the home button, wait enough for the android the release that activity from memory, and now you return to the activity using the task switcher. You come to the `TabLayoutActivity` since it was the last activity you left. Now I get this exception

Comment: then probably you shud try onAttach method. This gets called after onStart()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129224/discussion-between-roostaamir-and-rushi-ayyappa).

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible) {
        if(getActivity() != null){

        if (shouldGetData) {
            beginGettingData();
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Try this ...

Comment: Could you add more explanation as to why this might be correct?

Comment: I don't have a menu but still I will try it and inform others

Comment: this method will called when your fragment will visible or hide with true false parameter

Comment: still getting the same `not attached to activity exception`

Comment: as I said, I can't rely on conditions like `getActivity() != null` since I HAVE TO call the `beginGettingData()` so that I have something to show to the user

Comment: make a call in oncreateView  method in fragment and after fragment change update your fragment data from setMenuVisibility method

Comment: I used this method as well. The problem with this solution is that the ViewPager calls all of its fragment's `onCreateView` methods and I don;t want this to happen. I want to call each fragment's `beginGettingData()` individually

Comment: put SetMenuVisibility method in all fragments indually and perform actions when that fragment became visible , you will get flag true that fragment is visible or not

Comment: as I said, `setMenuVisibility` is causing the same `not attached to fragment exception` since it too is called before `onCreateView`

Comment: use safeguard like if (getActivity() != null) for your scenario

Comment: as I said, I can't rely on conditions like getActivity() != null since I HAVE TO call the beginGettingData() so that I have something to show to the user